# Appending an int to a string for each occurance

Tags: python, loops, rest

i have this list :

```
BJ;COTONOU;AAA-AAA-001;1.1.1.1;BJ;LI;Cotonou
BJ;COTONOU;AAA-AAA-001;2.2.2.2;BJ;LI;Cotonou

BJ;COTONOU;BBB-BBB-001;1.1.1.1;BJ;LI;Cotonou
BJ;COTONOU;BBB-BBB-001;2.2.2.2;BJ;LI;Cotonou
```

I am trying to append "_" + nth time 'AAA-AAA-001' show on the list.
So my goal would be to have a second list with :

```
BJ;COTONOU;AAA-AAA-001_1;1.1.1.1;BJ;LI;Cotonou
BJ;COTONOU;AAA-AAA-001_2;2.2.2.2;BJ;LI;Cotonou

BJ;COTONOU;BBB-BBB-001_1;1.1.1.1;BJ;LI;Cotonou
BJ;COTONOU;BBB-BBB-001_2;2.2.2.2;BJ;LI;Cotonou
```

Looking for some help here.

so far i have this :

```
with open('4.txt', 'r')as file1:
    read = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=";")
    for line in read :
        count = 1
        if line[2] in line:
            print(line[2] + "_" + str(count))
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `count` back to `1` whenever `line[2]` changes. Use a variable to hold its previous value, and check for a mismatch.

```
with open('4.txt', 'r')as file1:
    read = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=";")
    last = None
    for line in read :
        if line[2] != last:
            count = 1
            last = line[2]
        print(line[2] + "_" + str(count))
        count += 1
```

This code assumes that all the lines for the same `line[2]` are together in the file. If not, you'll need a dictionary that holds the counter for each prefix.

There's no point to `if line[2] in line:` -- how can a list element not be in the list?